# How do I get a response from Jenkins after triggering build remotely

Tags: javascript, post, jenkins

I am attempting to trigger a jenkins job from my company's machine and then return if it was a success or not. Currently I am able to trigger the job via the URL I create (masked for privacy), so I feel as though the URL is correct and the parameters are being passed correctly as well as they show up in the Console Output of the job and everything is ok there. However, I would like to know if the build was successful or not.

From most of the examples I see there is a response from jenkins with a status code indicating success (201). However, I never receive anything in my callback function. Any ideas?

```
function onButtonClick()
{
    var JenkinsURL = "http://mycompany:8080/view/project/job/jobname/buildWithParameters?token=TokenHere";

    var params = new Object();
    params.Data1 = "Data";
    params.Data2 = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        params.Data2 += list[i];
    }

    $.ajax(
    {
      url: JenkinsURL,
      method: 'POST',
      data: params,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: RebootCallback,
      fail: RebootCallback,
    }
    );
}

function RebootCallback(result)
{
    alert(result);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Triggering a build with the API like this just enqueues a build, waiting to be executed.  Therefore the API call returns immediately, without waiting for the build to start, or complete (it's possible that neither may happen).

But the response to your request will contain a `Location` HTTP header, pointing to the newly created queue item.  For example:

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Location: http://localhost:8080/queue/item/16/
```

Checking the API URL of this resource (i.e. append either `api/json` or `api/xml` to the URL) will return information about the queued item.

If the build is still in the queue, you'll see the `why` reason (e.g. waiting for an available agent), but if the build has been started, you'll see an `executable.url` field pointing to the build.  For example, the API JSON for a build that started:

```
{
  …
  "url": "queue/item/16/",
  "executable": {
    "_class": "org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun",
    "number": 16,
    "url": "http://localhost:8080/job/test/4/"
  }
  …
}
```

If you fetch the API URL for that build #4, you would be able to check its `result` field to get the build outcome.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense that it doesn't execute immediately. You say that the response to my request contains a location, but that's my issue, I am not receiving a response at all. Is there an issue with the code posted that would result in not receiving a response?

Comment: I don't know about the Javascript specifics. But some quick searches of this site mention jQuery auto-following redirects (though I guess that shouldn't happen for a 201 response), and CORS headers being required, if this Javascript isn't running on the same origin as your Jenkins server.

Comment: @BethSavis Did you find any solution for this. are you able to receive any other info in response apart from status code as 201.